# What to do with a circular dependency between two packages in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, wifi, rpm, broadcom

I am new to Fedora and recently installed Fedora 26 OS. I am trying to connect to wifi using that. I followed the youtube video [Broadcom installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TG_EHEWHQuM) and tried to install the Broadcom drivers. I have downloaded the rpm file **broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271-2.fc26.noarch.rpm** when I ran the command `rpm -ivh broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271-2.fc26.noarch.rpm` it says `wl-kmod >= 6.30.223.271` is needed.

I googled and found that it is the package **akmod-wl-6.30.223.271-13.fc26.x86_64.rpm** and when I try to install it it says `wl-kmod-common >= 6.30.223.271` is needed. When I googled I found that it is package **broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271-2.fc26.noarch.rpm**. It seems to be a deadlock as one require each other.

broadcom-wl - which has wl-kmod(akmod-wl) as requirement

akmod-wl - which has wl-kmod-common(broadcom-wl) as requirement

I have been struck in this for 2 days. Any suggestions on this regard will be helpful.

Comment: You could tell `rpm` to not to install dependencies (knowing you'll install them later anyways) by `rpm --nodeps`. Did you try installing this via `dnf` rather than `rpm`, that would typically take care of weird dependency configurations.

Comment: It's always better to avoid nodeps forcing. Usually it only brings more problems, than solves...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no problem if both rpm files depend on one another; just install the two together:

```
rpm -ivh akmod-wl-6.30.223.271-13.fc26.x86_64.rpm broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271-2.fc26.noarch.rpm
```

Logically; if there are more dependencies; you can install all of them together. If you don't want to hassle with all these dependencies; try installing the rpms with a package manager (like zypper or yum).

Comment: I think DNF is the default package manager in Fedora these days; it can be treated as yum for most purposes. Also, I run RHEL7 and use "yum localinstall" instead of "rpm -ivh". Keeps the database consistent and, as you say, solves some dependencies all by itself.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response I had some issues with my Fedora OS bootable pendrive and so had to install it in a hard drive. This command perfectly worked for me and I am right now commenting from where I have connected to wifi in Fedora after installing broadcom drivers. This saved me a lot of time!